# How to get x days before a certain date using isoformat?

Tags: python, datetime

How do I get x days before now using isoformat? This is what I have,

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
print datetime.now().isoformat() - timedelta(days=2)
```

Comment: `print((datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)).isoformat())`

Comment: (the above preceeded by: `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`)